# I'm having this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iePSn.png)

How to solve this error? My app is not running

Answer (score 0):

on your getcount method:
try doing -->return (dataList == null) ? 0 : dataList.size();